# AppleScript: ADDING file or folder permissions through Shell script

Tags: shell, applescript

I just can't get my head round this one :(
I want to add a user, say Joe Smith, to a (or several) folder's permissions. I created an applet with the following code :

```
on open thisStuff
try
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with this_item in thisStuff
            set thisObj to POSIX path of (alias this_item)
            set scrpt to quoted form of ("chmod -a \"joesmith:allow:read\"")
            do shell script scrpt & " " & thisObj with administrator privileges
        end repeat
    end tell
on error errStr number errorNumber
    error errStr number errorNumber
end try
end open
```

When I drop a folder on my applet, I get a "command not found" error.

If i go to the correct directory in the terminal and type :

```
chmod +a "joesmith:allow:read" my folder
```

it works without problem.
I guess something is wrong with my unescaping, or other syntax of my shell  script, but I just can't see it :(
Can anyone set me straight here please…

Edit…

Still hacking at it !! I tried it this way :

```
on open thisStuff
set pass to "mySecretPassword"
try
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with this_item in thisStuff
            set thisObj to POSIX path of (alias this_item)
            do shell script "sudo chmod -a " & "access_bpf:allow:read " & quoted form of thisObj password pass with administrator privileges
        end repeat
    end tell
on error errStr number errorNumber
    error errStr number errorNumber
end try
end open
```

… and this time I get error :

```
chmod: No ACL present 'Volumes/Path/to/my/folder/'
```

Mmmmmmmm… I can't figure it !!

Thanks again for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the first attempt, this works for me if I send {choose folder} to the open handler:

```
on open thisStuff
    --try
    tell application "Finder"
        repeat with this_item in thisStuff
            set thisObj to POSIX path of (this_item)
            set scrpt to ("/bin/chmod +a \"joesmith allow read\" " & quoted form of thisObj)
            do shell script scrpt with administrator privileges
        end repeat
    end tell
    --on error errstr number errorNumber
    --error errstr number errorNumber
    --end try
end open
```

You had an extraneous "quoted form of" in the line assigning your scrpt variable. Not sure about the colons in your chmod +a mode string, but I took those out, as I did not see that form in the man page description. Also, you used "-a" and "+a" at different times; +a is the correct form.